# how to use prepare select statement with variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepare

```
$colName = rent_due_date
```

I am trying to use `$colName` as my column name and run `SELECT` statement with that column name.

How can I use `$colName` in a prepared `SELECT` statement and echo `$row[$colName]`?

```
<?php
$colName =  $_GET['colName'];
$smt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM dhr WHERE ? < curdate()');
$smt = $pdo->bindParam(1,$colName);
if($smt){
if($smt->execute()){
while($row = $smt->fetch()){ 
?>
// echo in the table as below   
<td class="center "><?php echo $row[$colName];?></td>
```

**Error**

> Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()

Comment: First of all add `WHERE`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Oh Thanks, I have added now this error show `Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam() `

Comment: Try this: -> $smt = $pdo->bindParam(1,$colName,PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @Mubo Yes added `$smt = $pdo->bindParam(1,$colName,PDO::PARAM_STR);` still error showing as `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can only bind parameter on the `statement` object not the `PDO`
  connection.
  That's why you are getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()`
- You cannot bind column names as placeholders

so change:

```
$colName =  $_GET['colName'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dhr WHERE $colName < NOW()";
echo $query;
$smt = $pdo->prepare($query);
if($smt){
echo "prepare() sucess\n";
$result = $smt->execute();

    if($result){
    echo "execute() sucess\n";
    $data = $smt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($data);
    //display table
    }else{
    echo "execute() failed\n";
    }
}else{
echo "prepare() failed\n";
}
```

Comment: Why do i get downvote, i believe my answer is correct ?

Comment: Hi @meda i tried the above but still it show `Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bindPram()` Thanks

Comment: @sanainfotech thats not possible that you get the same error if you removed the pdo line, I gave you 2 more options check my edit.

Comment: Thanks @meda, I have tried both the bottom options no errors, but echo  not displaying in the table. `<td class="center "><?php echo $row[$colName];?></td>`

Comment: if I use `$smt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM dhr');` all my `echo $row['']` are working perfect. I think the Error is just in `STATEMENT`

Comment: @sanainfotech you need to debug this, try logging the SQL string and run it directly in you db. try it with `NOW()` instead

Comment: Yes in my localhost Myphpadmin I run this statement `SELECT * FROM dhr WHERE rent_due_date < curdate()` works fine

Comment: Yes in my localhost Myphpadmin I run this statement `SELECT * FROM dhr WHERE rent_due_date < NOW()` works fine as well